# Finalbuilder action studio unable to save the fbap file

Tags: finalbuilder

I am trying to save a new action created using final builder action studio in c/program files/finalbuilder/actiondefs. However, the fbap file is not shown in that location even if I navigate to that location. But if I use finalbuilder action studio and say open, I am able to see the fbap file in the location. I am unable to understand why. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a problem with UAC File system virtualisation. Run Action Studio as Administrator.

Comment: That means the file is probably stored below `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.